# Android google map - best practice for updating data

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application I integrated google map. When the map is opened its getting my current location and getting the peoples locations around me from remote server (with a radius of 5000m). Now what if the user moves the map like left, right, up whatever... I want to take the new locations from server which suits to the map at that moment. But I don't know the best practice for that. I can not possible send a query of each single touch (move) right?

Comment: if you are only worried about the people in the radius around you then why does it matter if the user moves the map?

Comment: when the map is just triggered that what i am interested in.. but if the user want to see the people in other location, i want to be able to travel inside the map and see other people

Comment: then yes you will have to make a call every time the map is changed.

Comment: yes but while user is dragging the map than i need for a 2 seconds drag like 1000 calls... there should be more reasonable way...

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, do the query after the map is finished moving

Comment: As @tyczj said, it is better to do query after the map finished moving, or have some cache acquired before. 

It is also good in terms of energy saving to make one batch query at the end, rather than a lot of small ones during the map movement.

Comment: how do i understand if the map stop moving?

Comment: you use the `onCameraChanged` listener

Comment: ok... i will give it a try... If you write it as an answer i will be happy to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to show makers outside of your radius then you will have to use the maps `OnCameraChangeListener` and when that fires is when the map has stopped moving so then you know it is time to get new data